# C - alternative using snprintf to prepare MySQL statements?

Tags: mysql, c

I've been tearing my hair out for a while on this one. The C code is called from a bash script, which loops through a command's output in a while loop and passes variables to the C script as args. It goes through a list and partitions data properly. I've been using the C MySQL api, and up until now everything has been relatively straight forward. It tries to run a SELECT(EXISTS) command to dictate whether to input a new row, or update an existing one.

I have typed the command into MySQL terminal and it works perfectly. I have even printf'd it and copied the command directly into the terminal. It works....

So why then, am I getting Syntax errors? I've tried escaping fields and input using backticks, single quotes and double quotes and I'm still getting this dumbounding error. I thought maybe it was something to do with the null space? But I'm at my witts end. Here's the code, any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
const int MAXLEN = 100;

/*  Compile with:
        gcc db.connect.c `mysql_config --libs` -O1
        for the best results
*/

/* Function definitions for later */
void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con);
int send_query(MYSQL *con, char query[MAXLEN]);

/* If any SQL commands fail, return an error message */
void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
  mysql_close(con);
  exit(1);
}

/* Helper function to send queries to MySQL database */
int send_query(MYSQL *con, char query[MAXLEN])
{
  if (mysql_query(con, query)) {
    finish_with_error(con);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Establish MySQL API connection, if not- fail with err
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL) {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    // Connection string. 
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "user", "password",
       NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    if (argv[1] == NULL){
        printf("No query passed, terminating script \n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argv[1] != NULL) {
        if( strcmp( argv[1], "--help" ) == 0 ) {
            printf("This program was created to interact with MySQL, by checking and updating live network stats\n");
            printf("It has 2 parameters, an IP address to look in the database for and a value to update a field by, \
                if that IP address is found. ");
            printf("If the value is not found, the program will insert a new row.");
            return 1;
        }

        // Works out how much memory to allocate to buffer for snprintf
        // Originally cmd_len was 65- as this was the amount of bits needed by the address string.
        // This was changed to MAXLEN to prevent SEGFAULTS and give the function breathing room.
        size_t cmd_len = MAXLEN;
        size_t param_len = sizeof(argv[2]);
        size_t q_len = cmd_len + param_len;

        // Allocates that memory to a buffer, referenced as query
        char *query = malloc(sizeof(char) * q_len);

        snprintf(query, q_len, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `analytics`.`live` WHERE `foreign_addr` = `%s`)", argv[1]);

        printf("%s\n", query);
        send_query(con, query);
        free(query);

        // Used to store the result of the MySQL select commands 
        MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
        if (result == NULL) {
            finish_with_error(con);
        }

        // num_fields stores the number of fields, i and x are counters, answer is 1 or 0
        int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
        int i = 0;

        // Loops through each row in the answer statement.
        // There will only be one row in the answer, which will be 1 or 0
        // Basically, if the IP is found.
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))){
            for (i=0; i<num_fields; i++) {
                // If the IP isn't in the table
                if(!atoi(row[i]))
                    send_query(con, argv[1]);

                // If the IP is already in the table
                if(atoi(row[i])) {
                    snprintf(query, q_len, "UPDATE analytics.live SET count=count+1 WHERE foreign_addr = '%s'", argv[1]);
                    printf("%s\n", query);
                    free(query);
                    snprintf(query, q_len, "UPDATE analytics.live SET dat_sent = dat_sent + %s", argv[2]);
                    printf("%s\n", query);
                    free(query);
                }
            }
        }
        mysql_close(con);
        return 1;
     }
    mysql_close(con);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `snprintf` is a huge problem here. Use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) whenever possible. You have a syntax problem because your syntax isn't correct. Hint: Don't use backticks for everything. [String literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) use different characters, but this is a non-issue if you properly separate *data from query* using placeholder values.

Comment: This opens the doors for a whole new line of research... Thank you for the advice

Comment: Originally, I didn't have the backticks thrown in there at all.. That was a meagre attempt at a quick-fix from my side... Could you please explain what you meant when you mentioned separating the data from the query? The main reason I was trying to use `snprintf` was becausue I was under the illsuon that was the best way to create the query strings...

Comment: As a general rule you should **never** insert data into your queries. Keep query and data separated, use placeholder values instead. Not only is this great from a C perspective, you don't have to keep cooking up custom query strings, but it's safer from a SQL injection one, you won't have those issues. The query should look like `WHERE foreign_addr=?` and then you can bind that vaue.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up... I didn't know that was an option. Whilst I do understand the implications of SQL injections, this particular application is writing via a private NIC, on an encrypted connection- and it's passing VPN usage statistics. How would I bind the values afterwards? The documentation is pretty dense, and I'm really constrained by time. Thanks again for all your help so far :)

Comment: SQL injection isn't just a security issue, it's a tear-your-hair-out, bang your head on the desk in frustration issue when you forgot to properly escape something or missed a single character in your syntax. The cost of doing it correctly the first time is low, arguably lower than doing it the sloppy way with hacks like `snprintf`, and as a bonus it's safer and more secure.

Comment: Back to square one then, I'm going to get to bed and pick this up again in the morning. I'll be sure to accomodate the prepared statements tomorrow- and from the sounds of it I'll never look back. (y)

Comment: Yes, parameterized queries are safer and generally superior to printf()ing; however, that’s not necessarily your problem. Please [cut down your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to just the problematic query without `—help` arguments and helper functions and logic we don’t need to see. As an aside, what do you think `sizeof(argv[2])` is doing?

Comment: regarding: `sizeof(argv[2]);` the `sizeof` will return the size of a pointer, rather than the length of the parameter.  Suggest: `strlen( argv[2] );`

Comment: regarding this kind of statement; `if (argv[1] == NULL){`  Much better to simply check `argc` to see if an expected number of command line parameters have been entered by the user

Comment: regarding: ` snprintf(query, q_len, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `analytics`.`live` WHERE `foreign_addr` = `%s`)", argv[1])` You question states that the passed in command length (argv[1]) needs 65 bytes, and only 100 bytes were allocated.  Therefore, this will overflow the buffer `query`

Comment: regarding: `if(!atoi(row[i]))`  the function: `atoi()` does NOT return a status,  rather it returns the converted value.  Which can be 0, so this statement is not reliable

Comment: regarding: `free(query);
                    snprintf(query, q_len, "UPDATE analytics.live SET dat_sent = dat_sent + %s", argv[2]);`   Do NOT pass the allocated memory, pointed to by `query` to `free()`, because then your application no longer owns that memory  I.E. writing on the (no longer allocated) memory is Undefined Behavior

Comment: regarding: `for (i=0; i<num_fields; i++) {
                // If the IP isn't in the table
                if(!atoi(row[i]))`  The call to `mysql_num_fields()` returns the number of columns in each returned row,  Not something of interest to the posted code.  This statement: `atoi(row[i])`  tries to convert the first column NAME to an `int`.  probably not what you want

Comment: Hold my hands up and say that there's a load of areas I need to research! I've revised the code and tried this: https://pastebin.com/PbBZMMp3 - However, I'm now getting an error which says: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. I've looked at various other examples of this and can't make head nor tail of it... Any advice?

Comment: According to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html) the "mysql_stmt_bind_param()" must be called BEFORE the mysql_stmt_prepare().

Comment: I've completely rebased the entire code using prepared statements, and I'm now running into a logic problem... Could someone take a look for me please? :) 

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139327/c-mysql-api-prepared-statements`